# Spring Expression Language - Size property on List

Tags: java, spring, expression

I am trying to use `size` property on List using Spring EL, which's throwing exception that size can't be found.

```
@Cacheable(value = "cache", unless = "#result.size > 0")
public List<Results> getResult();
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 8): Field or property 'size' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList'
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:85)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:43)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:346)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:84)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`size` resolves to `List#getSize()` which doesn't exist. Try with `size()` as follows:

```
@Cacheable(value = "cache", unless = "#result.size() > 0")
public List<Results> getResult();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just as the error states, size is not a property of ArrayList, it is a function. Try `size()`